# Is there a way to view Bing images without the feed?

Tags: images, web, bing

I want to load bing.com/images without having a bunch of images pop up. A blank screen like Google. And without logging in. I don't want to just have uBlock hide them, I want it so they don't have to load.

Possible?

Comment: Why do you want that

Comment: To load faster on slow internet, and Google Images is broken on my browser and I don't want to go through and mess with every single privacy setting to get it to work.

Comment: years ago Opera had an option to load images only when the user requests. I don't know if it still works nowadays but it's worth a try